# Send email using PHP mail() function through Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

How to make the **PHP** *mail()* function use my credentials in the **Amazon SES** to send transactional emails without using the PHPMailer lib or having to install and configure postfix or sendmail for this purpose?

Is it a good practice? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Amazon based Sendy to send any mail to number of people at a time. But its paid one.FYI it uses PHP mail() internally.